# How to write a Functional Interface that throws the same checked exception

Tags: java, lambda, interface, functional-interface

I know `Runnable` does not throw `Exception`, so I am trying to write a new interface that accepts method that can throw checked exception:

Interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    void run() throws Exception;
}
```

Service:

```
public void serviceMethod(MyInterface action) throws Exception {
    // ...
    action.run();
    // ...
}
public void serviceMethod(Runnable action) { // for methods don't throw checked exception
    // ...
    action.run();
    // ...
}
```

Main:

```
public void myMethod() throws Exception {
    service.serviceMethod(this::someMethodThatThrowsCheckedException);
    service.serviceMethod(this::someMethodThatDoesNotThrowCheckedException);
}
```

This all seems OK, but I don't want `myMethod()` to throw the base class `Exception`, I want it to throw the actual exception classes throw by `someMethodThatThrowsCheckedException`. e.g. if

```
public void someMethodThatThrowsCheckedException throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {//...}
```

Then I want `myMethod()` to throw `IOException, ClassNotFoundException`, instead of `Exception`. Just like the case when the method is called normally without going through the interface:

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    someMethodThatThrowsCheckedException();
}
```

Can this be done in a generic way?

Comment: `Runnable` does not throw `Exception` but [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) does.

Comment: @Pino Thanks but thats not my question

Comment: Why design with a checked exception? Most think that checked exceptions are an antipattern these days

Comment: @g00se its out of my control, some come from external library that are still throwing checked exceptions

Comment: @g00se Got a citation for that?  Checked exceptions are *very* useful.  I have lost hours upon hours of my time trying to figure out what exceptions certain frameworks (read: Spring) are capable of throwing.

Comment: Well, I think I would actually say *some* rather than "most". I can't find much, since SO seems to feature *very* heavily in searches including "java" ;) but here's one [thing](https://medium.com/@eob/checked-exceptions-considered-evil-f7d07e051fa6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create interface that *throws* generic exception:

```java
    interface MyInterface<T extends Exception> {
        void run() throws T;
    }
```

And one that *not throws*

```java
    interface MySuperInterface extends MyInterface<Exception> {
        void run();
    }
```

**usage:**

```java
MyInterface<IOException> io = () -> {throw new IOException();};
MyInterface<IllegalAccessException> iae = () -> {throw new IllegalAccessException();};
```

2. You also can create generic **consumer** method:

One for *throws*:

```java
    public static <T extends Exception> void consume(MyInterface<T> action) throws T {
        action.run();
    }
```

One for *no throws*:

```java
    public static void consume(MySuperInterface action) {
        action.run();
    }
```

3. And you be able to do this:

```java
    public static void mainMethod() throws IOException, IllegalAccessException {
        MyInterface<IOException> io = () -> {throw new IOException();};
        MyInterface<IllegalAccessException> iae = () -> {throw new IllegalAccessException();};
        MySuperInterface noException = () -> {};
        //can assign to runnable cause noException.run() doesnt throw an exception
        Runnable runnable = noException::run;

        consume(io);
        consume(iae);
        consume(noException);
    }
```

4. Full example:

```java
    interface MyInterface<T extends Exception> {
        void run() throws T;
    }

    interface MySuperInterface extends MyInterface<Exception> {
        void run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        mainMethod();
    }

    public static void mainMethod() throws IOException, IllegalAccessException {
        MyInterface<IOException> io = () -> {throw new IOException();};
        MyInterface<IllegalAccessException> iae = () -> {throw new IllegalAccessException();};
        MySuperInterface noException = () -> {};
        //can assign to runnable cause noException.run() doesnt throw an exception
        Runnable runnable = noException::run;

        consume(io);
        consume(iae);
        consume(noException);
    }

    public static <T extends Exception> void consume(MyInterface<T> action) throws T {
        action.run();
    }

    public static void consume(MySuperInterface action) {
        action.run();
    }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hey, really nice! Addressed 90% of my question! Thank you! The only part remaining is what if the action throws multiple exceptions?

Comment: I think there is no way.  Probably do something like this: https://onlinegdb.com/qvwe3QhUi

Comment: That is really interesting! And I agree its a working solution, well done!